# AgularJS - format checkbox list json result

Tags: json, angularjs, format

I try to format a dynamic json result from a checkbox list without success.

Here is a plunker of what I want to achieve: http://plnkr.co/edit/TR5ZtE

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('AuthorsCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.users = [
    {'id':1,'name':'julien'},
    {'id':2,'name':'laurent'}
  ];

  $scope.authors = {};

});
```

HTML

```
  <label ng-repeat="user in users">
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{user.name}}" ng-model="authors[user.name]">{{user.name}}
  </label>

  <div>
    <h4>JSON result</h4>
    {{authors}}
  </div>

  <div>
    <h4>Result wanted</h4>
    julien & laurent OR julien OR laurent
  </div>

</body>
```

So for now, I get a Json result that I want to format in a string value.

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little change to the template

```
<label ng-repeat="user in users">
  <input type="checkbox" value="{{user.name}}" ng-model="user.checked">{{user.name}}
</label>

<div>
  <h4>JSON result</h4>
  {{users | myFilter}}
</div>
```

And a filter:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function(){
  return function(data){
    return data.filter(function(p){
      return p.checked;
    }).map(function(p){
      return p.name;
    }).join(" & ") || "none"
  }
})
```

When you initialize (or fetch) your model add checked property:

```
$scope.users = [
  {'id':1,'name':'julien' , 'checked':true },
  {'id':2,'name':'laurent', 'checked':false},
  {'id':3,'name':'john'   , 'checked':false}
];
```

Comment: If you want to manipulate arrays do not cast them into an object unless you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: How would you do to have a default checked box? I know how to have a default checked box but it's not in sync with the filtered value (showing "none") until I check/uncheck a box...

Comment: Ok thx for your answer, but I'm getting my model from http request. So I need to do a loop through it and add these values?

Comment: aren't you saving the checked property to the server?

Comment: No, I'm building a news/blogging system. The purpose of this app is to get all the authors from http request (laravel app), do a checkbox list with it and allow to update dynamically the current article. I'm new to AngularJS so I'm not sure if I'm doing it properly...

Comment: do you want all to be checked as default?

Comment: No just the actual (not modified) author(s) by default as it an "edit article" page

Comment: Please show more of your code and models so I can understand

Comment: Ok I'll create a new thread where I'll explain what I'm trying to achieve more precisly and let you know. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

to format a string, I think the quickest way in angular would be a filter, I made you a quick and dirty version( http://plnkr.co/edit/05yyKz?p=preview ) :

```
.filter('toText', function(){
  return function(jsonRaw){
    if(jsonRaw){
      andVal=[]
      for(var i in jsonRaw){
        if(jsonRaw[i])
          andVal.push(i);
      } 
      return andVal.join(' & ');
    }
  }
})
```

It takes a JSON input with { value : true/false } (the standard output from the set of checkboxes) then for each true value it creates a string with the & and the OR (unless there is only one box selected) which result in the desired output

To call it you just have to pipe it :

```
{{authors | toText}}
```

The same thing could be done in a function in the controller, the result would be the same, but with less portability

Have fun

Comment: actually I totally misinterpreted your issue, I thought you wanted both OR and & values (quite unclear in you sample) I edited my answer to provide you the good output (without modifying your HTML code)